# iCloud/iCal can't accept/decline invitations?

Tags: icloud, ical

When I receive an invite I do not get an email nor does the invite appear in iCal.

If I log on to iCloud.com I do see the invite but when accepting/declining I get a message that my Calendar is not responding anymore:

> The ancestor is the aggregate of the child record, but it is not in the changelog.....